# Java Swing Component

Tags: java, swing, overlay

I am quite new to Java Swing and layouts. I want to create a component like this:
[image]

Comp 3 spans the height of 1 and 2. So, I imagine I will have to use overlay layout to position comp 3 behind 1 and 2. I want them to resize in these same proportions (they can be arbitrarily decided). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: I'm not understanding your requirement so I can't make a suggestion. I have no idea how the height of panel3 (background panel) is determined or how the heights of panels 1/2 are determined. How can they be the same proportion and arbitrarily decided?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of one or multiple `GridBagLayout` layout managers.
`GridBagLayout` allows you to place your elements in a grid-like manner by specifiying the proportions and positioning using the class `GridBagConstraints`.

```java
public void setupLayout() {
    JPanel container = new JPanel(); // the main holder of the elements
    // The numbered panels according to your screenshot
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(), panel2 = new JPanel(),
            panel3 = new JPanel(), panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.RED); // giving them colors for better visualization
    panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    panel4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridwidth = gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0; gbc.gridy = 0; gbc.weighty = 0.2;
    panel.add(panel1,gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 1; gbc.weighty = 0.3;
    panel.add(panel2,gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 2; gbc.weighty = 0.5;
    panel.add(panel3,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1; gbc.gridy = 0; gbc.gridheight = 3;
    panel.add(panel4,gbc);

    // Code to place your container in a frame or whatever usage you have for it...
}
```

The properties `gridx` and `gridy` specify the position you are on the grid.
`weightx` and `weighty` specify how much space (on a 0 to 1 proportion) they take up.

Unlike `gridwidth` and `gridheight` they specify how much does a cell take up relative to other cells so a cell will take up a space equal to the space that `gridheight` cells take up vetically or `gridwidth` cells take up horizontally.
So, to be explained in action, since `panel1` is set to `weighty = 0.2`, `panel2` is set to `weighty = 0.3` and `panel3` is set to `weighty = 0.5` we're saying that whatever cell is on the first row, will always take `0.2` of the vertical space, second row `0.3` of vertical space and third row half (`0.5`) the vertical space, therefore `panel4` will take up the same space as how many cells heights sum up to the prior, if `panel4` was set to `gridheight = 2`, it will take as much space as two rows take up, since in this example it's placed on the first row, it will take up therefore a space equivalent to that of the first and second rows, which is half the vertical space (`0.2 + 0.3`), but since we set it to `3` which is also the maximum number of rows in this example, it will take up all of the vertical space.
Mixing up `gridwidth`/`gridheight` and `weightx`/`weighty` is commmon therefore you have to be aware of the difference.
Note that using the `gridwidth`/`gridheight`/`weightx`/`weighty` will only "reserve" the space you're specifying, and the elements will be placed inside that spaced anchored to the side specified in the `anchor` property.

In order to make the elements scale up to their reserved space we set `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` where `BOTH` stands for filling up the space *both* horizontally and vertically (the other three choices being, clearly, `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL` and `GridBagConstraints.NONE` which is the default value that represents no filling at all.
[image]

Comment: They are stating "*Comp 3 spans the height of 1 and 2. So, I imagine I will have to use overlay layout to position comp 3 behind 1 and 2.*" which suggests that they need the yellow panel to occupy the space under the red and blue components too. Maybe you could use a `JLayeredPane` with `GridBagLayout` for your `container` instead of `JPanel` to achieve this. Or maybe use `OverlayLayout` indeed.

Comment: i actually think they meant that it is equal to the space taken by 1 and 2. but not literally in the same space, as in the area of 3 is the sum of the areas of 1 and 2, because his screenshot doesn't show 3 containing 1 and 2 but as a third separate component